# How do i export neo4j 1.9.9 version data to newer version

Tags: neo4j, export-to-csv

I am using neo4j 1.9.9 version, I have lots of data in it, I want to export all the data and import into newer version of neo4j, any one has any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to export it into a smart csv structure (depending on your data design) and then reimport it with the [csv importer from neo4j-admin.](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) I think this would be the fastet for an big data set.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as neo4j-admin command is not recognized by neo4j 1.9.9. This feature has been developed for neo4j 3.0 and greater, Is there any alternative way to do this..

Comment: Yeah but you can write a script or tool to export to csv? And then use the importer?

Comment: Your right, I am finding a simpler way to do this, as my graph db contains millions of nodes and millions of relationships, it will be very difficult task to create such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for this, if you want to migrate data, then just copy your graph.db folder and paste it in exact greater version of current using version 
for example: if you are using 1.9.9 version paste it into 2.0, and go on repeating the same, from 2.0 to 2.1.
Don`t directly copy to greater version, it can give you version not matching error